# How to eliminate duplicate WebElement in Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

I'm using POM framework where I have creates page classes for my application pages. Lets say there are 2 page in my application 1. Event 2. Timeline. So I have create 2 page classes

**EventPage.java**

```
public class RCON_D_EventPage 
{

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Search for entered records']")
    public WebElement eventSearchBox;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='btn rc-gray-bg rc-dashboard-contact-btn ng-scope']")
    public WebElement eventSearchButton;


    @FindBy(xpath="//p[@ class='rc-found-record no-padding ng-binding ng-scope']")
    public WebElement eventSearchResult;

    @FindBy(xpath="//div/span[@class='ng-scope']")
    public WebElement searchResultNotFound;

    @FindBy(xpath="//li/button[@ng-click='goToFirstPage()']")
    public WebElement nextPageButton;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@ng-click='clearFilters()'][1]")
    public WebElement clearFilterButton;


    WebDriver driver;

    public RCON_D_EventPage(WebDriver driver)
    {

        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    public void enterTextInEventSearchBox(String text)
    {
        eventSearchBox.clear();
        eventSearchBox.sendKeys(text);
    }

    public void clickEventSearchButton()
    {
        eventSearchButton.click();
    }

    public String getEventSearchResult()
    {
        return eventSearchResult.getText();
    }

    public String getNoRecordFoundMessage()
    {
        return searchResultNotFound.getText();
    }
    public void clickNextPageButton()
    {
        nextPageButton.click();
    }
    public void clickClearFilterButton()
    {
        clearFilterButton.click();
    }
}
```

**TimeLinePage.java**

```
public class RCON_D_TimelinePage 
{

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Search for entered records']")
    public WebElement timelineSearchBox;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='btn rc-gray-bg rc-dashboard-contact-btn ng-scope']")
    public WebElement searchButton;

    @FindBy(xpath="//p[@class='rc-found-record no-padding ng-binding ng-scope']")
    public WebElement searchResult;

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='row ng-scope']")
    public List<WebElement> totalFoundRecords;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='No data found']")
    public WebElement noResultMessage;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@ng-click='clearFilters()'][1]")
    public WebElement clearFilterButton;

    public RCON_D_TimelinePage(WebDriver driver)
    {

        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void enterTextInSearchBox(String text)
    {
        timelineSearchBox.sendKeys(text);
    }
    public void clickSearchButton()
    {
        searchButton.click();
    }
    public String getSearchResult()
    {
        return searchResult.getText();
    }
    public int getFoundRecordCount()
    {
        return totalFoundRecords.size();
    }

    public String getNoResultFoundMessage()
    {
        return noResultMessage.getText();
    }

    public void clickClearFilterButton()
    {
        clearFilterButton.click();
    }
}
```

So here in Both page there are some common WebElement e.g. `//input[@placeholder='Search for entered records']` or `//button[@class='btn rc-gray-bg rc-dashboard-contact-btn ng-scope']` and so on. So it there any way that I can manage this redundancy in Page Object Model ?

Comment: You can move the common webelements into a base class. Though I have to say both the search classes look very similar in fields and methods. Maybe look at refactoring the logic into one class and use delegation to that class when you need to use the search functionality from other pageobjects.

Comment: This should be kept separate based on page level as per your current model, that way it is easy to determine and locate. In future, if the element property changes which might remain same in other page can create a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composition (is-A, has-A relationship) in this case.

**has-A Relationship**

you can create a Page Class for search and copy all the methods inside this class. And all the other Page class which has this element, you can just create the object of this Page.

The following example shows `has-A` relationship.

```
class SearchPage{
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Search for entered records']")
    public WebElement timelineSearchBox;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='btn rc-gray-bg rc-dashboard-contact-btn ng-scope']")
    public WebElement searchButton;

    public SearchPage(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void enterTextInSearchBox(String text){
        timelineSearchBox.sendKeys(text);
    }
    public void clickSearchButton(){
        searchButton.click();
    }
}


public class RCON_D_EventPage{
    SearchPage searchPage;
    public RCON_D_EventPage(WebDriver driver){

        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);
        this.driver=driver;
        searchPage = new SearchPage(driver);
    }
}
```

**is-A Relationship**

You can achieve the same thing using `is-A` relationship as well. What I mean is you can extend each and every class which needs search functionality with `SearchPage` class.

Personally, I would suggest to use has-A Relationship as it make more sense, in terms of programming rather than is-A as mentioned below.

```
public class RCON_D_EventPage extends SearchPage{

    public RCON_D_EventPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);
        this.driver=driver;

    }
}
```

Comment: thank , it seems feasible . I will implement the same

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a common header or maybe just a search box on the two pages. What you would do in this case is to just create a page object for the header/search box area. It would contain the elements

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Search for entered records']")
public WebElement eventSearchBox;

@FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='btn rc-gray-bg rc-dashboard-contact-btn ng-scope']")
public WebElement eventSearchButton;
```

which can then be removed from the two existing page objects. You would instantiate the header page object whenever needed, no matter what page you are on.

Don't think of page objects as representing a full page. Think of them more like a widget object where a widget can be a full page or just part of a page with functionality that is repeated on different pages.

Read more here:

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html